# Calculating the center of mass of a random shape in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, shapes

How can I calculate the center of mass of any shape in javaFX? 
In this code I have an intersection between a circle and a square and it can be an intersection between any 2 shapes so I need a method to calculate the center of mass of an intersected shape independently from the 2 original shapes. So far my center of mass of the intersected shape is the sum of the max and min borders divided by two (Which is not really the center of mass).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Intersection extends Application {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Pane playfield = new Pane();
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 900);

        root.setCenter(playfield);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        Circle c1 = new Circle();
        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle();
        playfield.getChildren().addAll(c1,r2);
        c1.setCenterX(300);
        c1.setCenterY(300);
        c1.setRadius(200);
        c1.setFill(Color.RED);

        r2.setX(400);
        r2.setY(400);
        r2.setHeight(400);
        r2.setWidth(400);
        r2.setFill(Color.BLUE);

        Shape intersection = null;
        intersection = Shape.intersect(r2, c1);
        double gcX = (intersection.getBoundsInParent().getMaxX() + intersection.getBoundsInParent().getMinX()) / 2;
        double gcY = (intersection.getBoundsInParent().getMaxY() + intersection.getBoundsInParent().getMinY()) / 2;

        Circle gravityCenter = new Circle();
        gravityCenter.setCenterX(gcX);
        gravityCenter.setCenterY(gcY);
        gravityCenter.setRadius(2);
        gravityCenter.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        intersection.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        playfield.getChildren().add(intersection);
        playfield.getChildren().add(gravityCenter);

        System.out.println(gcX + " " + gcY);

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```